# C# MS Office PPT to Image conversion

Tags: c#, interop, export, powerpoint, office-interop

I am a beginner with C# and windows programming. I have written a service which converts a powerpoint file to individual slide images using the `slide.export` method that the `microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint` libraries provide. I am able to get all the slides but some of them seem to be broken and i see a `"Image cannot be displayed. Memory exceeded"` or the likes of it. I thought it was insufficient memory and then just tried it with a ppt having one slide(whose image was broken) and to my dismay I found the single image to be broken as well.

Am I using export wrongly or should I pass different arguments than I am passing already? I will paste the code below.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application appPpt
    = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objActivePresentation
    = appPpt.Presentations.Open(strFilePath,
                                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed,
                                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide objSlide
                                                   in objActivePresentation.Slides)
{
    //Names are generated based on timestamp. 
    objSlide.Export(slideName, "PNG", 960, 720);
    objSlide.Export(slideNameMedium, "JPG", 307, 231);
    objSlide.Export(slideNametn, "JPG", 150, 113);
}
```

I'm in need of help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try SaveAs.
Hope it helps.....